# IE Event is null

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, simulation, jxbrowser

I am trying to simulate blur event in IE using JXBrowser.

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" onblur="test()">
```

and the function "test"

```
function test(){    
    alert("1");    
   alert(event.srcElement);    
}
```

when I try it manually in IE, I get it work perfectly, but when I run using JXBrowser it pop's up the first alert (alert("1")) but then says: "Unable to get value of the property 'srcElement': object is null or undefined".
Why when I run JXBrowser it simulates the event but then it says that the event is null?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, `event.srcElement` is called `event.target` in other browsers. Generally you can write this:

```
var element = event.srcElement ? event.srcElement : event.target;
```

Comment: Or shorter:
var element = event.srcElement || event.target;